# Is budget-additive function a modular set function?

Tags: additive-combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization

We know that budget-additive function 
$$
    f(S) = \min\{B,\sum_{i \in S}w_i\}
$$
where $w_i$ is positive constant and $B \ge 0$ is called additive budget.

Is it also a modular set function?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is a counterexample.

Let $S = \left\{ 1, 2 \right\}$, $T = \left\{ 1, 3 \right\}$ and $w_1 = w_2 = w_3 = 50$, $B = 75$.

Then $f(S) + f(T)$ is not equal to $f(S \cup T) + f(S \cap T)$ because

\begin{align}
  f(S) + f(T) &= 75 + 75 \\
  f(S \cup T) + f(S \cap T) &= 75 + 50.
\end{align}

So, although the budget-additive function $f(S) = \min\left\{ B, \sum_{i \in S} w_i \right\}$ is submodular, it's not modular unlike the linear function $f(S) = \sum_{i \in S} w_i$.